# No se ejecuta el switch en C, en sublime text, ¿Por qué?

Tags: c

Este programa ingresa un numero de base y otro como limite y un carácter i para impares o p para pares.

Me pide los valores (todo bien hasta ahí); el problema es que no se ejecuta el switch, saliendose del programa.

IDE: sublime text
SO: UBUNTU

```
int numero1,limite;
char letra;

int main(){

    printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&numero1);

    printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&limite);

    printf("Ingrese la i para numeros impares o p para pares: ");
    scanf("%c",&letra);

    fflush(stdin);

    switch(letra){
        case 'p':
            for(int i=numero1; i<=limite; i++){
        
                if(i%2==0){
                    printf("%d ",i);
                }
            }   
        break;

        case 'i':
            for(int i=numero1; i<=limite; i++){
        
                if(i%2!=0){
                    printf("%d ",i);
                }
            }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: El truco mágico aunque no lo creas es agregar un espacio antes del `%c`, en vez de `scanf("%c",&letra);`, has esto: `scanf(" %c",&letra);`. No ocupas el `fflush(stdin)`

Comment: Emprime en pantalla el texto que se ingresa, y asi podrás ver si en verdad está llegando lo que esperas que llegue, un char

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que las lecturas previas de `scanf` dejan el salto de línea en el buffer.

Así, supongamos que un usuario reproduce la siguiente secuencia:

```
Ingrese el primer numero:
> 1
Ingrese el segundo numero:
> 7
Ingrese la i para numeros impares o p para pares:
> p
```

En stdin encontraríamos la siguiente secuencia (si se introdujesen las 3 entradas de una vez):

```
1 \n 7 \n p \n
```

Pues bien, el primer `scanf` lee el primer entero, dejando stdin con el siguiente contenido:

```
\n 7 \n p \n
```

Nota que el salto de línea se mantiene en el buffer de entrada. Ahora le llega el turno al segundo `scanf`. `scanf` detecta que el primer caracter es un separador (salto de línea, espacio, tabulador), así que lo descarta. Después encuentra un dígito numérico y empieza a leer hasta que ya no hay más dígitos. `stdin` queda ahora así:

```
\n p \n
```

Ahora se hace la tercera llamada a `scanf`. Esta llamada, a diferencia de las anteriores, `%c` no descarta los separadores. `scanf` no sabe si tu intención es leer el salto de línea o no, así que deja en tus manos la capacidad de elegir. Como no le has dicho nada, se limita a ofrecerte el primer caracter que encuentra en `stdin`, es decir, el salto de línea.

Para prevenir este comportamiento basta con añadir un espacio a la lectura de caracteres:

```
scanf(" %c", &letra);
//     ^
//     un espacio
```

Como nota adicional, `fflush`, de acuerdo con la [documentación](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) solo debe utilizarse con *streams* de salida. Invocar a `fflush` con un *stream* de entrada tiene un comportamiento indeterminado. Es decir, el comportamiento final de esa llamada dependerá del compilador que se use en cada momento. Así que es conveniente no usar `fflush` con `stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

para mi el problema esta que no se limpia el buffer al cargar las variables, tengo entendido que es recomendable hacerlo siempre. prueba los siguiente:

```
    printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&numero1);

    printf("Ingrese el segundo numero: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&limite);

    printf("Ingrese la i para numeros impares o p para pares: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&letra);
```

espero te sirva!!! saludos!

Answer (score -4):

el truco del compañero que puso el comentario funciona, también otra variante o truco es leer el caracter como una cadena: `scanf("%s",&letra);` también funciona. Saludos

Comment: Es más bien un comentario que una respuesta.

Comment: Gracias  a cada uno de ustedes por tomarse el tiempo de haber leído mi problema y compartir sus conocimientos conmigo, el cual fue de mucha ayuda. Logrando resolverlo satisfactoriamente.